# Xamarin - MVVM Cross Data Binding Resources

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-resources

I am starting a cross-platform project in Xamarin, and I have some doubts that are me to prevent development. Initially the project is only for android and UWP but in the near future it will be also for iOS.

Questions:
1. I want to centralize all resources (strings for labels like "Name", "Age") in order to be consumed in the 3 platforms and when you have to edit this string, the change is made on all projects. What better way to do this? I need to do DataBinding on UI in all plataforms

[Xamarin.Android] I researched and heard of anything like "MVVMCross" but this forces me to extend my activities other own the MVVMCross and for example, and uencessito to take Android one ActionBar and for that I need to extend a class that can extender "AppCompatActivity" being, however, can only extend an activity and that therefore can not extend the actitivties from the MVVMCross.

Video: https://youtu.be/_DHDMNB_IeY?list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W

Like:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity // (with MVVMCross use MvxAppCompatActivity )
public class MainActivity: BaseActivity // (with MVVMCross use MvxActivity)
```

2. For assets, the correct approach is to keep the assets in the project, and if they are common to pass the PCL? I ask this because the assets on Android, iOS and UWP, the dimensions are different. What is good practice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For string resources and translations located just in your PCL I would suggest to use this library (very simple to implement):
https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable/, but you can also try and implement Resx files from your PCL.

**Adding MvvmCross to your project just for localization would be just crazy**.
But if you already use MvvmCross in your project, there´s a plugin for translations that uses json files at the PCL level: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#jsonlocalisation.

For question 2: You can embbed resources in your PCL and load them from platform projects (ios/android/etc), but it won´t be as obvious as loading platform resources (you´ll need additional code). Thus, your assets and images usually change across platorms (different resolutions, dpi and design style guides) so trying to put them all together may complicate things more than helping.

About using specific MvvmCross Activities: that´s the way it works.